# PHP MYSQL proclaimed error in SQL syntax but insert still work

Tags: php, mysql

At my wits end, looked for answers (even found previous questions of similar nature with no good solutions)..

I have a very simple INSERT statement:

```
$sql_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('23') "); 
    if (mysql_query($sql_query))
        {
            echo "Record inserted";
        } else {
            echo "Error inserting record: " . mysql_error();
        }
```

When I execute this code, the data is inserted into the DB, it works.

But, I get an error displayed?

Why would the query work (data is inserted into the table) but throw an error?
No matter what I do to adjust the query, I can not get "Record inserted" to echo.

If it helps, my table is a single column with unique index.

Thank you in advance for any help offered!

Comment: Simple, you're querying twice. `mysql_query()`. I am SO NOT putting an answer for this. It's pointless; pardon the pun.

Comment: it should be `if($sql_query)`

Comment: Please **stop using `mysql`**, that extension is ***deprecated***, read [***the big read box that says "warning"***](http://php.net/mysql_query), learn to use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead (the replacement extensions for `mysql`)

Comment: Oh, never mind reading the comments, they're not working today.

Comment: Wow... I cant believe stupid mistake I made.. Thank you for pointing out with out flaming me!

Comment: *Flaming* - That term existed even before the Internet was available for us pilgrims. Ah, the days of BBS's.

Comment: I think `$sql_query` is rather misleading - it's no wonder you saw it and thought it would go in a query function! SQL queries are string variables, but the output of this function is a _resource_ type. I tend to use `$result` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running your query twice:

This succeeds, and returns a statement handle:

```
$sql_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('23') ");
```

Then you try to execute that statement handle, which fails:

```
if (mysql_query($sql_query))
```

Basically, your problem boils down to "I put this frozen pizza into the oven and baked it for twice the time required. Why is it burnt?"

Comment: Ever feel... like.. an.. idiot... The second I read your answer I saw the issue.. It stood out like a sore thumb!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mysql_query` on a query that has already been executed. Try changing your code to this:

```
$sql_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('23') "); 
    if ($sql_query)
        {
            echo "Record inserted";
        } else {
            echo "Error inserting record: " . mysql_error();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('23')"; 
    if (mysql_query($sql_query))
        {
            echo "Record inserted";
        } else {
            echo "Error inserting record: " . mysql_error();
        }
```

Comment: Please always explain mistakes, so that others can easily see what was done wrong.

Comment: Please edit your post and include some explanation on what is wrong with the OP's code, and how do you propose to fix it. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better!